# did not route page to payment blade file in laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel

in My laravel 5.6 app I have following route link to payment.blade.php file in payments view files,

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{route('payments.payment',$vehicles->id)}}" role="button">Go Premium</a>
```

route for this page is,

```
Route::get('myads/{id}/edit/payment', function(){
    return view('payments.payment');
})->name('payments.payment');
```

and in payment.blade.file i have following form action,

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('payments.payment', ['id' => $vehicles->id])}}">
{{csrf_field()}}
```

it is execute route is,

```
Route::get('/add-order/{id?}', 'PController@addOrder')->name('payments.payment');
```

normaly I need go payment blade file via above link and form submit using blade submit buttons. but here my application when I click **go premium** button to visit payment blade file it is not redirect to payment buttons. it is execute payment blade file form action with out displaying payment blade file. how can I fix this problem?

**please see my edited routes and form action**

```
Route::get('myads/{id}/edit/payment', function(){
    return view('payments.payment');
})->name('payments.viewpayment');
```

and

```
Route::post('/add-order/{id?}', 'PController@addOrder')->name('payments.payment');
```

and form action

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('payments.viewpayment', ['id' => $vehicles->id])}}">
```

but now got this error,

```
(1/1) MethodNotAllowedHttpException
```

how can fix this?

**adOder function**

```
 public function addOrder(Request $request,$id = null)
{

    DB::table('vehicles')
            ->where('id', $id)
            ->update(['adtype' => '1']);
}
```

**current codes**

```
Route::get('myads/{id}/edit/payment', function($vehicle_id){
return view('payments.payment',compact('vehicle_id'));
})->name('payments.payment');

Route::post('/add-order/{id}', 'PController@addOrder')->name('payments.payment');
```

link to payment blade

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{url('myads/'.$vehicles->id.'/edit/payment')}}" role="button">Go Premium</a>
```

form action,

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('payments.payment', ['id' => $vehicle_id])}}">
```

and controller,

```
public function addOrder($id = null)
{
    DB::table('vehicles')
            ->where('id', $id)
            ->update(['adtype' => '1']);
}
```

Comment: because you use same name for both `routes name('payments.payment'); ` use diff name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use same name for `get` and `post` methods for same view

In your anchor tag

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{url('myads/'.$vehicles->id.'/edit/payment')}}" role="button">Go Premium</a>
```

In your Routes file

```
Route::get('myads/{id}/edit/payment', function($id){
return view('payments.payment',compact('id'));
})->name('payments.payment');

Route::post('/add-order/{id}', 'PController@addOrder')->name('payments.payment');
```

And in your form tag

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('payments.payment', ['id' => $id])}}">
```

You need to Redirect back with success message in your function

```
public function addOrder($id = null)
{
    DB::table('vehicles')
        ->where('id', $id)
        ->update(['adtype' => '1']);

    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Successfully added');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try with diff `name routes`

Routes

```
Route::get('myads/{id}/edit/payment', function(){
    return view('payments.payment');
})->name('payments.viewpayment');
Route::post('/add-order/{id?}', 'PController@addOrder')->name('payments.payment');
```

Action

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{route('payments.viewpayment',$vehicles->id)}}" role="button">Go Premium</a>
<form method="post" action="{{route('payments.payment', ['id' => $vehicles->id])}}">
{{csrf_field()}}
```

Comment: the two routes still have the same route names, please update.

Comment: use `<form method="post" action="{{route('payments.payment', ['id' => $vehicles->id])}}">` not `viewpayment` in action

Comment: got this error **Undefined variable: vehicles (View: C:\Users\Nalaka\Desktop\acxian\resources\views\payments\payment.blade.php)**

Comment: you just see the tutorial how to routes in laravel you clear the all thing about it